# How to use stored procedures parameter to work of multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got this final table in SQL Server:

| ID | Ad_Date | Nurse | Nurse_Date | Doc | Doc_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 323 | 2022-06-23 09:00 | Molly | 2022-06-23 09:10 | John | 2022-06-23 09:15 |
| 699 | 2022-06-23 08:00 | Jane | 2022-06-23 08:17 | NULL | NULL |
| 878 | 2022-06-23 07:00 | Molly | 2022-06-23 07:10 | John | 2022-06-23 09:08 |
| 886 | 2022-06-23 09:00 | NULL | NULL | Joe | 2022-06-2 08:15 |

And I have a stored procedure with a parameter `@Date`.

What I'm asking is how to use the parameter `@Date` so it will show only the rows in which one of the columns with dates (`Ad_date` or `Nurse_Date` or `Doc_Date`) is updated.

For example: if I pass in '2022-06-23 09:10' as `@Date`, the code should only return the first row.

But if I pass in '2022-06-23 09:07' as `@Date`, the code should return the first and last rows.

I did it for 1 column:

```
 Ad_Date >= (CASE WHEN @Date IS NULL THEN Ad_Date ELSE @Date END)
```

but how can I do it for either 1 of the three column?

Like I wrote above

Comment: At least you need to show us your stored procedure so that we can see what is wrong. Also show sample data and the expected result

Comment: Have you tried using `OR <condition> OR <condition> OR <condition>`...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like Stu said in the comments it worked with OR... easy solution:

```
 WHERE (Ad_Date >= (CASE WHEN @Date IS NULL THEN Ad_Date ELSE @Date END
   OR (Nurse_Date >= (CASE WHEN @Date IS NULL THEN Nurse_Date ELSE @Date END)
   OR (Doc_Date >= (CASE WHEN @Date IS NULL THEN Doc_Date ELSE @Date END))
```

Comment: please mark this as an answer if it worked with you

Comment: 'You can accept your own answer in 2 days'

Comment: You can simplify without `CASE` expressions (e.g. `WHERE (Ad_Date >= @Date OR @Date IS NULL)`). Consider adding an `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` query hint for this "kitchen sink" query to avoid reusing a cached execution plan optimized for a different mix of parameter values.